# How to Fix CSS div to bottom of parent element?

Tags: html, css

I need to fix child element to bottom of its parent element, in my case I have "Back Button" and need it to bottom of scrollable content so I cannot use `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0`, but I can add `position: fixed` with `bottom: 0`, but problem is that it is at bottom of window not parent element.

Summary: Fixed button at the bottom of crollable content somewhere on the page

```css
results {
 position: relative;
 height: 200px;
 width: 200px;
 border-top: 2px solid gray;
 border-radius: 1px;
 background-color: #424242;
 color: #dfdfdf;
 font-size: 15px;
 font-family: Arial;
 padding: 10px;
 overflow-y: auto;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 max-height: 200px;
 max-width: 200px;
 transition: .5s;
}
.return-btn {
 position: absolute;
 height: 30px;
 width: 65px;
  bottom: 10px;
 background-color: tomato;
 color: white;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 1px;
 outline: 0;
 font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 19px;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: .5s;
}
.page {
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="results">
    <p style="text-align: center;">some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br></p>
    <button class="return-btn">< Back</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Post your related code please.

Comment: Sorry, It is there ;)

Comment: And the relevant HTML.

Comment: Can you change the HTML? If you can, just add another container to hold the button. http://jsfiddle.net/3j6ng2qo/

Answer (score 0):

you can do: `position: fixed;` to the element and add a parameter like: `bottom: 0;` and/or `left: 0;` and just make the parent element full height or something.

Maybe float it above all the elements with a: `z-index: 2;` parameter or something of the sort. Again without the additional code its kind of hard to tell what the real issue is with the code you have shown in the pictures.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, fixed, I have already do that but when I changed resolution the button was at same position. I provided code so you can help me better. But thanks for replying

Comment: You need to remove the back button from its parent container if you want it positioned toward the bottom of the browser. Its being bound by its parent per the code you have provided which looks like its causing this error.